# Is the return every iteration of reduce method stored in accumulator or in adults?

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

```
      // reduce method
const adults = humanAge.filter(function (age) {
        return age >= 18;
      });
      const avg =
        adults.reduce(function (acc, cur) {`enter code here`
          return cur + acc;
        }, 0) / adults.length;
      return avg;
    };
```

Is the return every iteration stored in acc or in adults ?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  `adults` will be an array containing all the elements of `humanAge` that were greater or equal to 18.  `adults.reduce` returns a single value (the sum of the array elements), which is then divided by the size of the array (giving the average), stored in `avg` and returned.

Comment: I understand that But I mean, is with each iteration the output is stored inside the accumulator and then at the end it is stored inside the avg, or is the storage directly in the avg?

Comment: At the end of the `reduce`, it is divided to give the result. What passes along in the `reduce` is the total adult age

Comment: `acc` is just a temporary.  For the first call to that function, the 0 is passed in as `acc`.  The return from that function is then passed to another call to the function, where the next element is added in.  When the `adults` array is emptied, the result of the function is returned as the result of `adults.reduce`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every return inside reduce is added inside acc
when loop will be finished, your acc will be the value of your variable